# Set ticks precision with pgfplotsset

Tags: pgfplots, labels

First, this forum has been a great resource for me for some time now. I recently started using `pgfplots` and `tikz`, so some things I still need to figure out. 
I hope my question will be clear and the MWE is ok...

I export my plots from Matlab using `matlab2tikz`. Some of my data happens to be in a range as shown, where standard precision on the ticklabels is not sufficient to distinguish them (everything is labeled as "1" on the y-axis). I can do the format change manually in each plot, but I really would rather do it using `\pgfplotsset` before my actual `tikzpictures` begin.
What should I add to the `\pgfplotsset` command to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotsset{%
    every axis plot post/.append style={line width = 2pt}}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[title=Trying to set precision with pgfplotsset]
\addplot +[domain=0:1] {(x+rnd)/4000+1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title=Precision set manually inside tikzpicture,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,precision=4]
\addplot +[domain=0:1] {(x+rnd)/4000+1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can simply move the `/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=4` to `\pgfplotsset{}` , or am I missing the point?

Comment: I tried all sorts of things, except for the obvious... it works, haha! Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure. Welcome to the club of the confused :D Is it OK for you if we close this question as too localized since the problem is solved?

Comment: Yes, fantastic!